# Query timeout expired - ASP Classic (VB). Timeout happens in client browser, not on server

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, timeout

I'm having some troubles with timeouts on my website. It has a rather large newsletter receiverlist (approx. 100k recievers). We deliver a tool for sending out newsletters, and based on the query for the newsletter (segmentation fx), we make show a total number for recievers of the newsletter.

If I run the query through SQL Server Management Studio I get a result in roughly 2 seconds. But if the querye is run through a client browser I get the same timeout evert time: "`[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Query timeout expired`".

I have tried adjusting the Server.ScriptTimeout parameter but with no luck. It seems as there's a problem with the data connection, but that's where I get stuck.

I'm hoping some of you brilliant people know the answer to this one :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [`Connection Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) property of the connection string?

-- EDIT --
PS: I know I've given you a VB.NET page, but the connection strings will be pretty similar.